# how to compare values of a column and add a counter if the same value is found

Tags: python, linux, compare, multiple-columns

I have the file *energy.txt*:

```
path   energy      counter
AXX    100.00          1
AXX     99.99          2
AXX     99.98          1
AXX     99.50          1
AXX     99.00          7
```

I want to compare the values of the second column and if the difference between them is less than 0.02, keep the second value and add a counter.

For example, the first step would be 100.00 - 99.99 = 0.01 (less than 0.02) so

```
path   energy      counter
AXX     99.99          3   
AXX     99.98          1
AXX     99.50          1
AXX     99.00          7
```

The second: 99.99 - 99.98 = 0.01, so

```
path   energy      counter
AXX     99.98          4
AXX     99.50          1
AXX     99.00          7
```

The third: 99.98 - 99.50 = 0.48 (greater than 0.02)

The fourth: 99.50 - 99.00 = 0.50 (greater than 0.02).

I want to do this in Python.

Comment: what module do you plan on using for this? do you want to do it simply using a .txt file or are you planning on using a database?

Comment: What happens when there are values like: 100.00, 99.99, 99.98, 99.97, 99.96, 99.95? How do you want to group the .02 intervals?

Comment: In your posted example, should the energy on third line of `energy.txt` be 99.98 instead of 99.99?

Comment: @PurityLake It is just a simply .txt file.

Comment: @MichaelDavidWatson You are right, I've already thought about that. But for my example the probability for this to happen is none.

Comment: @unutbu Yes! I made a mistake, it is 99.98

Answer (score 1):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)-style:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(filename, sep='\s+')

# generate a value (label) with which we can group rows together
label = (df['energy'].diff() < -0.02).astype('int')
df['label'] = label.cumsum()
print(df)
#   path  energy  counter  label
# 0  AXX  100.00        1      0
# 1  AXX   99.99        2      0
# 2  AXX   99.98        1      0
# 3  AXX   99.50        1      1
# 4  AXX   99.00        7      2

# Aggregate the count for each label group
grouped = df.groupby(['label'])
counts = grouped[['counter']].agg('sum')
print(counts)
#        counter
# label         
# 0            4
# 1            1
# 2            7

# Find the index of the row with the minimum energy per group
idx = grouped['energy'].agg(lambda col: col.idxmin())

# Select only those rows from df
result = df.ix[idx, ['path', 'energy', 'label']]

# Merge in the computed counts
result = pd.merge(result, counts, left_on=['label'], right_index=True)
result = result.ix[:, ['path','energy','counter']]
print(result)
```

yields

```
  path  energy  counter
2  AXX   99.98        4
3  AXX   99.50        1
4  AXX   99.00        7
```

Comment: Thanks @unutbu. I am using "Enthought Canopy" and installed pandas module. I tried to run it and got this: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    181             else:
    182                 filename = fname
--> 183             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

Comment: /Users/DavidMoraFonz/scripts/python2.py in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_table(delete2.txt, sep='\s+')
      4 
      5 # generate a value (label) with which we can group rows together

NameError: name 'delete2' is not defined.  My file is : delete.txt and the script : python2.py.

Comment: These error messages are really hard to read in the comments. Please put them in your original post (at least temporarily) so they can be properly formatted. It looks like you are getting `NameError`s. These occur when Python encounters a variable name that has not been defined. For instance, `pd.read_table(delete2.txt,...)` should be `pd.read_table('delete2.txt',...)`. The quotes tell Python `'delete2.txt'` is a string, not a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using a dictionary:

```
with open("abc") as f:
    next(f)
    dic={}
    counter=1
    dic[counter]=map(float,next(f).split()[1:])
    for line in f:
        curr=map(float,line.split()[1:])
        if abs(dic[counter][0]-curr[0])<0.02:
            dic[counter]=[curr[0], dic[counter][1]+curr[1]]
        else:
            counter+=1
            dic[counter]=curr

for key in sorted(dic):
    print dic[key]
```

**output:**

```
[99.98, 4.0]
[99.5, 1.0]
[99.0, 7.0]
```